# Jquery in Checkbox

Tags: jquery, textbox, radio-button

I have multiple html checkboxes that all have different names.

What I have to do is when it is checked it should disable some radio button that has a different name.

I know it can be simply done using jquery.

Any help...with a simple example..thanks

Comment: Can someone just make a great big sign in the middle of the homepage that explains how to deal with a checkbox/radiobutton in jQuery? This question comes up pretty much every day.

Comment: I believe that sign already exists in the form of www.jquery.com

Comment: Apparently, that sign isn't big enough, I think we need one with neon lights or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input[name=theName]:checkbox").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("input[name=radioName]:radio").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        $("input[name=radioName]:radio").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Shorter way:

```
$("input[name=theName]:checkbox").click(function() {
    $("input[name=radioName]:radio").attr("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

.....

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $("input[type=radio]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }
   else
   {
     $("input[type=radio]").removeAttr('disabled');
   }
 });
```

Comment: When it's unchecked I would *assume* it should re-enable the radio, though the OP hasn't been perfectly clear on this.

Comment: @karim79: agreed and fixed, forgot that, yes he is not much clear, i have posted rather impractical solution because he has now shown names :(